# Download YAML file system using node from Github

Tags: node.js, git, github

I have a bunch of yaml files stored in github.

```
team1.yaml
team2.yaml
team3.yaml
...
...
team100.yaml
```

I can extract them all into a zipball using: https://github.com/my-repo/zipball/master which works great. But I don't understand how I use this zipball on my node server. I need not only the name of the files, but more importantly their content.

My desired output is the YAML files in a JSON object to use in my client side application.

Any ideas?

Comment: you'll need to use an npm module to unzip the zip ball, there are many, do a search on npm for zip, unzip, or extract and find one that suits. Once extracted you'll read the files and parse them with js-yaml or similar which will give you your JS Object.

Comment: I have seem a bunch of these npm modules, but none of them let me use a remote url to grab the zip, they all look to require the zip to be on the server

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use `request` or similar to fetch the zipball. You should be able to pipe it to an unzip module then write the files to disk or even parse them in memory.

Comment: Could you provide a bit of pseudo code as an answer that I can mark as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise), [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or other module to download the zipball and store it on your drive. You can use [node-tmp](https://github.com/raszi/node-tmp) to create a temporary directory to store it in.

Unzip the zipball with an [appropriate module](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/zip), I don't have a recommendation.

Parse files into JS objects with [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml)

Start with the basics first and get it working. Once you have that you can decide if you need to move to avoiding disk writes and attempting to do it in memory, but that likely wouldn't be the best option.